# One-to-Many Processor streaming with JPA

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a SCDF processor which produces multiple outputs per input. The list of outputs could be rather large. That's why I was thinking of streaming the results from JPA repository.

```java
@Service
public class ProcessorFunction implements Function<Parent, Stream<Message<Child>>> {

    @Autowired
    private ChildRepository repo;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Stream<Message<Child>> apply(Parent parent) {
        try (var stream = repo.findByParentId(parent.getId())) {
            return stream.map(GenericMessage::new);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public interface ChildRepository extends  JpaRepository<Child, Long> {
  
  Stream<Child> FindByParentId(long id);
}
```

I expected that the stream will send the list of output on the output channel. However, only `null` values are being sent.

I have gone through [spring-cloud-dataflow document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_configuring_the_scdf_server) as well as spring-cloud-stream documentation but could not find my use case.

Kindly help!

Comment: You can't return a stream of persistent objects out of a transaction

Comment: ! Well that's a bummer. What else can I do to prevent all the results loading in memory? Can I convert them into a DTO and send? Alternatively, can I send them to output channel programmatically from within a transaction?

Comment: I don't know what you're planning to do with the results, but you have basically two options: 1) do whatever you have to do during the transaction 2) save the results in a local intermediate storage (file)

Comment: I am planning to send them to kafka topic

Comment: I would try the first approach

Comment: I suggest exploring the JPA finder method returning a Flux and then you also return a Flux from the apply method by mapping from result.